# OAuth2 login working with gtm-oauth-2, not with google-api-objc-client

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, oauth, gtm-oauth2

I first implement [gtm-oauth2](https://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2) on my app to test the OAuth login with Google. Then, as I need access to Google Calendar, I delete `gtm-oauth2` and I've installed [google-api-objectivec-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client). Now, I get the following error :

```
2015-02-25 17:10:10.782 Reset[17368:76612] Invalid parameter not satisfying: windowNibPath
```

I'm using this code (I tried with obj-c, got the same error):

```
let controller = GTMOAuth2WindowController(
    scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
    clientID: "aze",
    clientSecret: "aze",
    keychainItemName: "aze",
    resourceBundle: nil
)

controller.signInSheetModalForWindow(mainWindow, completionHandler: { (auth: GTMOAuth2Authentication!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        Context.shared.user.auth = auth
})
```

I try to understand why since two days. Any idea ?

EDIT : I've [created a repo](https://github.com/nicolas-besnard/osx-GoogleConnect) which reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to modify the file `OAuth2/Mac/GTMOAuth2WindowController.m` line 117-118

```
NSString *nibPath = [bundle pathForResource:nibName                                                                                        ofType:@"nib"];
self = [super initWithWindowNibPath:nibPath owner:self];
```

by

```
self = [super initWithWindowNibName:nibName owner:self];
```

Looks like the library use and old way to init window. Hope this can help someone.